# Excel VBA how pick up the integer in one column

Tags: vba, excel

How can I separate integer and text in columns? like:

```
12      44
abc     566
41      vvv
132     788
-12     -45
cbgd    -13
33      sut
```

there are so many column like this,How can I pick up all the integer in columns and paste in other sheet in frequency? like:

```
12      44
41      566
132     788
-12     -45
33      -13
```

Comment: And you want VBA for this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your task can be completed without VBA programming.

Here suppose your data is stored in 2 columns,
(If not, please convert it as below: you may split your 1 column data by using Excel 'Text Import Wizard' and choose 'Space' as your delimiter.)

```
+---+------+-----+
|   | A    | B   |
+---+------+-----+
| 1 | 12   | 44  |
+---+------+-----+
| 2 | abc  | 566 |
+---+------+-----+
| 3 | 41   | vvv |
+---+------+-----+
| 4 | 132  | 788 |
+---+------+-----+
| 5 | -12  | -45 |
+---+------+-----+
| 6 | cbgd | -13 |
+---+------+-----+
| 7 | 33   | sut |
+---+------+-----+
```

After, you got above table:

1. Open Excel 'Go To Special' dialog (Press: F5 > Special).
2. Choose 'Constants' and pick 'Text' checkbox only. This helps you
   select all non numeric cells.
3. Open Execl 'Delete' dialog (Press: CTRL and Minus sign-).
4. Select 'shift cells up'.
5. Done!!!

---

[Edited/Added] Thanks for [L42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2685412/l42) +1 and reminding me I should provide a VBA solution.

Here is the very simplified VBA code for deleting non-numeric cells and Shift-up.
The logic is similar to above manual method, you can also get similar code by Excel macro recorder.

Suppose you have a table in Excel similar above, then you can run this. Remeber to select the cell range before you run the code.

```
Sub DeleteNonNumericCellShiftup()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Selection
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If Not (IsNumeric(rCell)) Then rCell.Delete (xlShiftUp)
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, cel As Range
    Dim intOnly, i As Long

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Set rng = Selection
        For i = 0 To rng.Columns.Count - 1 '~~> to handle multiple columns
            Set rng2 = rng.Offset(0, i).Resize(, 1)
            For Each cel In rng2 '~~> generate an array of integers
                If IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
                    If Not IsArray(intOnly) Then
                        intOnly = Array(cel.Value)
                    Else
                        ReDim Preserve intOnly(UBound(intOnly) + 1)
                        intOnly(UBound(intOnly)) = cel.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            '~~> pass the array to Range, change the sheet name to suit
            Sheet3.Range("A1:A" & UBound(intOnly) + 1) _
                .Offset(0, i) = Application.Transpose(intOnly)
            intOnly = "" '~~> re-initialize variable
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Above code copies all integers in your current selection in Sheet3.
Is this what you're trying? HTH

Comment: THX a lot, I finish the task without VBA, but I will still try this VBA way.

Answer (score 0):

The IsNumeric function is a good place to start. For numbers that have been formatted as text (for instance with a single quote ' preceding them) try testing if you can format them as a number, e.g.

```
IsError(Trim(Format(The_Value, Format:="0.0")))
```